# simplexml_load_file multiple equals nodes

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML:

```
<user>
    <name>Name</name>
    <jobs>Job 1</jobs>
    <jobs>Job 2</jobs>
</user>
```

I read the file in this way:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file->getRealPath());
```

I'm able to get name attribute by:

```
(string) $xml->name
```

But if I try this:

```
$jobs = $xml->jobs
```

I have only one job in my `$jobs` variable

How can I change my code to get all jobs from xml?

Comment: perhaps `print_r($xml->jobs,true);` is worth a try?

Comment: What I need is to get two jobs from my XML I got just one using my code. No need to print it

Comment: do they both appear if you try `print_r`?

Comment: One appears without true. Passing true print_r is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$xml->jobs` in SimpleXML is short-hand for `$xml->jobs[0]` - that is, it just gets you the first element with that name. It's what lets you do "simple" things like `$xml->node1->node2->node3->etc` to quickly drill down into a document.

If you want to loop over all nodes with the same name, then you can just use a standard `foreach` loop (since they implement PHP's [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface):

```
foreach ($xml->jobs as $job) {
  // do something...
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to just fetch the entire collection of nodes as an array (in order to pass them to another function, for instance), you can use the `xpath` method to search for nodes by name (amongst other things):

```
$jobs = $xml->xpath('jobs');
```

See https://3v4l.org/9lcio